# How to edit a date of type Date in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

What I want to do:
Display a graph that shows the sun altitude during the day (It looks somewhat like a sin curve)
You should be able to select a location(latitude & longitude) and a date and the graph should be shown according to this.

I have imported a library that spits out an altitude for a given time and date at a given location.

```
// The date is passed from another component using react-date-picker. The date looks like this: 
Sat Mar 13 2021 13:54:56 GMT+0100

var altitude = SunCalc.getPosition(date, 10.757, 59.91).altitude * 180 / Math.PI
```

The problem:
This only shows the altitude at 13(1 PM) however I want to get a value for every full hour of the day.

So I thought I could use a for loop for this. Something like:

```
let altitudes = []    

for(let i; i<24; i++){
      let date = 'Sat Mar 13 2021 {i}:00:00 GMT+0100'
      var altitude = SunCalc.getPosition(date, 10.757, 59.91).altitude * 180 / Math.PI
      altitudes.push(altitude)
}
```

(This is not all the code, just so you get an idea)

However, this seems really hacky since I have to turn the date into a string and then manipulate it. Is there any smarter way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `i` value is not updating as per your logic.

```
'Sat Mar 13 2021 {i}:00:00 GMT+0100'
```

try using js string interpolation

```
`Sat Mar 13 2021 ${i}:00:00 GMT+0100`
```

or string concat

```
'Sat Mar 13 2021 '+ i + ':00:00 GMT+0100'
```

Not sure it will solve your problem

Comment: Oh, that was just some pseudocode. Just so that people understand my idea

Comment: you can try `moment.js` in that case

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert it to string, although it works.

Simply use Date built-in methods such as [setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)

```
let altitudes = []    

for(let i; i < 24; i++){
      date.setHours(i)
      var altitude = SunCalc.getPosition(date, 10.757, 59.91).altitude * 180 / Math.PI
      altitudes.push(altitude)
}
```